# Send transaction with same nonce as another transaction but lower gas price

Tags: web3js, raw-transaction, nonce

I want to send a transaction using web3, and I want this transaction to have the same nonce as other transactions - so far so good. The issue comes when I set a lower gasPrice than the other transactions. When I do this, I get an error:

> Replacement transaction underpriced

I am aware that the transaction is underpriced compared to the existing ones, but still I want it to issue the transaction instead of throwing an error and messing up the whole program.

Is there a way to circumvent this? Should I use any other API for this purpose? or am I doomed to always be the highest bidder?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to send the same transaction with *lower* `gasPrice`: If both transactions are in mempool, **the miners pick the transaction with the higher** `gasPrice` (your first transaction), so there's no need to add the second one.

If, for whatever reasons, you **really** want to have the same transaction with lower gasPrice, you could do the following:

- [cancel the pending transaction](https://jakubstefanski.com/post/2017/10/ethereum-cancel-pending-transaction/) - this costs gas, because it actually sends a 0 ETH transaction to itself, with a **higher** gasPrice than the original tx
- re-submit the original tx (with its `nonce` increased ), with a lower `gasPrice`

I can't imagine any scenario where this would be of any help, but it's definitely possible.

Comment: Thank you for your wisdom. Believe it or not this case exists.

Comment: cool. I'm glad my answer helped you